# How to install node 8.10.x after I have installed v12.18.2 on my Ubuntu 1804

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04

The question is pretty much as it's described in the title.  I have nodejs installed already (think it's installed by the apt-get), and the version is 12.18.2.  Now, I want to install 8.10.  How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Installing NVM allows you to switch between different versions of Node: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0):

For this you can install nvm that is node version manager after installing you can run command

```
nvm ls-remote //this will list all the available node version
nvm install v8.10.0 // this will install the node 8.10.0
nvm ls //this will list all the current installed node

nvm use v8.10.0 //this to switch between version
```